# Passing arguments while launching program from browser

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, registry

I am trying to launch an application (.exe) from my browser.

The specific app needs 4 arguments/parameters when launching, which are: firstname, lastname, id, info

Is there a way to add these arguments on the Internet Explorer address bar when i launch my program?

I mean something like this:

"myapp:// -firstname -lastname -id -info"

(I only managed to add those arguments straight to the windows registry, it worked that way. But thats no help... i need them to be inputted when launching the app )

I have added this to my windows registry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myapp]
@="URL:myprogram Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myapp\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\myapp.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myapp\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myapp\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vsa\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\myapp\" "%1"
```

Thanks for help already! I hope someone knows how to fix this... :)

ps. Im using windows 7 64 bit and Internet Explorer 10.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply pass multiple command line arguments to your application (unless they're listed explicitly in the registry as you've shown).

Instead, you must code your application's executable so that it is able to process the Application Protocol URL string. So your code is invoked by the browser like so:

```
C:\apps\myapp.exe "myapp:myParam?myParam2&myParam3&myParam4"
```

The executable must be able to process this string and handle it appropriately. You must take care to avoid security holes in the parsing of this string, as ANY webpage could exploit a hole here to escape the browser sandbox and attack the user's system.

There's more information on Application Protocols in this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/14/url-protocols-application-protocols-and-asynchronous-pluggable-protocols-oh-my.aspx